Data Quality Control Tools
I have a question around options for data QC.
Imagine that I have a data product.  The data is produced through a series of extractions, ETLs, customizations and prepared for handover.
I would like to know what options exist (either off-the-shelf products, or technology stacks) for me to execute an automated "Data Quality Control".  The data QC would be a series of tests to determine if all columns expected are present, naming conventions are followed, and perhaps even to verify that a portion of the expected values are present within the dataset.
The tool should be able to produce a high level "clean\anomalies present", along with a more detailed breakdown of the individual test results.
What's your intuition for the best approach for a need like this?
Thanks so much.
